# How do I pass back the data of a parent DOM element with a knockout binding on the child binding?

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js

I know that the data and event are passed with every function call from a knockout binding but is there a way to pass back the data of the parent element of the element focused on? I know this isn't right but something along the lines of this.

```
data-bind="event: { 
              focus: function() { $root.addAllocation($parent-DOM-element.$data)}
           }"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [event binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) has the answer. It supposes something like following code:

```html
<input data-bind="event: { focus: myFunction }" />
```

And this Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    myFunction: function(data, event) {
        console.log(event); // Check out the props for this one.
        alert('see console log');
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The `event` argument is the regular event from the `focus` event, and has -amongst others- a `target` property that holds a reference to the DOM. From there you can traverse up the DOM to find the parent and whatnot, using vanilla JS or your favorite JS library.

If you want you can then use the [KO methods to get `dataFor`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) an element.

Note though that this kinda goes against the spirit of Knockout. Better is to nest your view models, and give them access to eachother (parent knowing about the children or vice versa).